# How to run existing react-native project with java-11

Tags: react-native, java-11

I have create project using **react-native init ProjectName**. This project was created with java-8 version, but now I have changed my system and because of no more support for java-8 installed java-11 in system, So I have to use java-11 with my existing project.

When I run the code after starting npm using the command **npm-start & react-native run-android**, what issue I am getting is -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

**What went wrong:**

**Could not determine java version from '11.0.2'.**

I have tried to change android configuration like gradle version and other but still no luck.

I also searched online but couldn't get satisfied answer, most of the answer is saying that uninstall java-11 and install java-8.

I also gone through the official website of react native still no luck. 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22487

OS  - Ubuntu 18.0.4
Java vrsion install -11.0.2
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0
node - v10.15.3
npm - 6.4.1

"dependencies": {

```
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0",
"react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
"react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
"react-native-navigation": "^2.3.0",
"react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.3.1",
"react-native-tabbar-bottom": "^1.0.4",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
"react-redux": "^6.0.0",
"prop-types": "^15.6.2",
"redux": "^4.0.1"
```

},

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

ext {

```
buildToolsVersion = "28"
minSdkVersion = 19
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

}

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

I just want to run my project in java 11 which is already working fine in java-8, because now unable to install Java -8 in my ubuntu system.